# showing error when iam trying to import xlsx file into R

Tags: r

```css
d=read.csv(file.choose())
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\xforce47\Desktop\airbnb .xlsx'
```

```
d=read.csv(file.choose())
```

Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:\Users\xforce47\Desktop\airbnb .xlsx'

Comment: why you read excel file using `read.csv`?. try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+excel+in+r)

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you try to read in an excel document with a function for csv's. Try

```
library(rio)

d <- import(file.choose(), setclass = "tbl")
```

instead. The `setclass` argument is optional and only useful if you work with the `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the file as .csv and read it. 
Set the working directory correctly
x <- read.csv(‘myfile1.csv’)